# Installing Anaconda for a user with no home directory

Tags: python, installation, conda

How can I install Anaconda for a user that does not have a home directory. I keep getting errors like

```
CondaError: Cannot write to condarc file at /home/www-user/.condarc:
Caused by FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
```

I an using the PREFIX variable to set my root folder, but the installer keeps trying to put things into this nonexistant directory.